# Vertically align a div in a parent which has height auto AND min-height set?

Tags: css, center, vertical-alignment

I'm stuck on this one.

I want to vertically center a div. Its parent has an unknown height, however, **it does have a min-height**.

How can I do this?

Comment: The div to be aligned, does it have specified dimensions? and what other elements are in the parent container?

Comment: Reworded for clarity, Better title.

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one approach using the CSS3 transform property.

Use absolute positioning to place the top edge of the child element at 50% from the top, and then use the `transform: translateY(-50%)` to adjust for the child's height.

```css
.parent {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 200px;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    position: relative;
}
.child {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.content {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">child</div>
    <div class="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis velit ut neque tempor quis cursus tortor suscipit. Curabitur rutrum magna vitae arcu pharetra eget cursus ante accumsan. Nunc commodo malesuada adipiscing. Pellentesque consequat laoreet sagittis. Sed sit amet erat augue. Morbi consectetur, elit quis iaculis cursus, mauris nulla hendrerit augue, ut faucibus elit sapien vitae justo. In a ipsum malesuada nulla rutrum luctus. Donec a enim sapien. Sed ultrices ligula ac neque vulputate luctus. Suspendisse pretium pretium felis, in aliquet risus fringilla at. Nunc cursus sagittis commodo.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice move, I like it ... So bad it needs the child to be 'absolute' positionned. But I think it can do the job in most of the cases ...

Comment: position absolute ruins the default horizontal alignment though, now you have to set it to something and it overlaps other elements.

Comment: the need of position absolute removes the fluidity from this solution, sadly table/table css is still the way to go for cross-browser

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend this usage, but you can use a `display:flex` on the parent element, and use one of the following, according to your needs, on the child item :

> The `flex-direction` property establishes the main axis.
>
> The `justify-content` property defines how flex items are laid out along the main axis on the current line.
>
> The `align-items` property defines the default for how flex items are laid out along the cross axis on the current line.
>
> The `align-self` property defines how a single flex item is aligned on the cross axis, and overrides the default established by align-items.

*Source : [Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)*

This guide can be helpful to understand the mechanism : [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

---

**/!\ Warning** :

- flexbox properties are really attractive (I have been really interested in them some times ago) but they become really instable as soon as you use some `absolute` positionning within the DOM.
- flexbox properties needs some vendor prefixes for not-even-so-old version of almost all browsers. And sometimes the properties does not even have the same names (there are the *old*, *tweener* and *new* syntaxes. See the end of this post : [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))

Answer (score 1):

An other solution requires Javascript.

Javascript can help you to get the real height of the parent element :

```
var myElt = <your parent selector>;
var myEltHeight = myElt.offsetHeight;
```

After that, you can set the 'line-height' property of the parent to be equal to this height,

```
myElt.style.lineHeight = myEltHeight + 'px';
```

And finally add a 'vertical-align: middle' to him.

```
myElt.style.verticalAlign = 'middle';
```

Of course you have to re-do the maths each time the parent element is resized (with a window resizing for instance)...

For the record, I did not test this solution. It probably needs some adjustments  ...

Answer (score 1):

Use a table display, like this:

```css
div {
  height: 80vh;
  /* Random height and width */
  width: 80%;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  display: table;
}
p {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Some centered content.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't want to specify a fixed height, so this solution won't work.